# How do you include 3rd party javascript libraries in Meteor.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

In meteor if I want to use a 3rd party javascript library such as gridster.js (http://gridster.net/)

How do I do this? Usually I would just include the script inside the html page, but is there a way to require it directly in the javascript file just like how you can require frameworks in node.js?

Is it possible to use browserify with Meteor.js?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**EDIT**

**FOR Meteor 0.8+**

For **client** only third party libraries

adding your library files in `client\lib` folder is enough

For **Server** side NPM Modules

first add `meteorhacks:npm` package

It will create `packages.json` file in root folder

then in that file add your npm packages with exact version numbers,like

```
{
  "redis": "0.8.2",
  "github": "0.1.8"
}
```

Then you can use the packages with the following syntaxes

```
var GithubApi = Meteor.npmRequire('github');
      var github = new GithubApi({
          version: "3.0.0"
      });

      var gists = Async.runSync(function(done) {
        github.gists.getFromUser({user: 'arunoda'}, function(err, data) {
          done(null, data);
        });
      });

      return gists.result;
```

Documentation for the package https://github.com/meteorhacks/npm

**before 0.8**

You can include third party libraries by adding the required .js files to `clien/lib` folder

Then you can use them in your project.

If you want to use npm packages just add

```
mrt add npm
```

to your project and you can use like below

This example uses skimlinksjs npm package

```
var skimlinks = Meteor.require('skimlinksjs');

            skimlinks.setup("xxxx");
            var skimlinks_query = Async.wrap(skimlinks.query);

            var pro_id="productId:\""+s_string+"\"";

            var result = skimlinks_query({
                                searchFor: pro_id,
                                fq: "country:US"
                                });
```

Comment: Once you do 'mrt add npm', do you just npm install <package name> in the meteor app directory and it will install the npm package in that directory?

Comment: That's for serverside though. Seems like the question was for client side (gridster is for the client side)?

Comment: I've added both for client and server in my answer, I'll edit answer for better understanding